# Does blocking halve fall damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does Blocking with a sword still halve fall damage?  The wiki says that it did before the release, but doesn't exactly clarify whether or not this is still implemented.

Comment: lets test it and find out

Comment: This seems pretty easy to test yourself..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Even if you block with your sword, you will receive exactly the same amount of fall damage as you would if you weren't blocking.